# Wrapping text during print Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am printing a few variables in a row. One of the variables is a very long string that I want to wrap the text (currently it's printing half a word at the end of a line if it has to) so I would like the whole word to start on the next line if all of it will not fit o nthe previous line.

For example:

```
print(item.name,":",item.description,"\n\nValue :",item.value)
```

I need item.decription to wrap. I can wrap the whole lot if that helpds, but I don't want to end up with characters left on the screen fro mthe wrap operation in any case. I tried:

```
import textwrap
print(item.name,":",textwrap.wrap(item.description),"\n\nValue :",item.value)
```

but this doesn't work. The words don't wrap and I get square bracket characters and random commas instead in the output. How should I accomplish what should be a pretty simple wrap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`textwrap.fill()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) instead, it joins the lines with newline characters:

```
print(item.name, ":", textwrap.fill(item.description), "\n\nValue :", item.value)
```

`textwrap.wrap()` returns a *list* of wrapped lines.

Comment: Currently this is yielding unexpected results. I'll update the question

Comment: Please do; but note that the immediate problem you had was that `.wrap()` returns a list, while `.fill()` joins that list into one string with newlines. If you then run into other problems, that might be a *new* question you could post.

Comment: I was considering it, but didn't want to spam. Question has been updated

Comment: I will create a new question